# get contact name into android app and save it

Tags: android

In my Android application I want to access the contacts in the device and choose one of them and store them in the application to be sent a message by voice command.
I have successfully selected the contact and sent the message but I have a problem that when I exit the application the contact is cleared and I have to select it every time I go to the application ... Can I store it in the application and keep it always? How can I do that?

this code allow to access contacts and select one.

```
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, @Nullable Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    if(requestCode==PICK_CONTACT){
        if(resultCode== Activity.RESULT_OK){
            Uri contactData=data.getData();
            Cursor cursor=getContentResolver().query(contactData,null,null,null,null);
            if(cursor.moveToFirst()){
                String name=cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(ContactsContract.Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME));
                nameset.setText(name);
                String con_id=cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts._ID));
                int has_phone=Integer.parseInt(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts.HAS_PHONE_NUMBER)));
                if(has_phone>0){
                    Cursor phoneCursor= getContentResolver().query(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_URI,null,
                            ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTACT_ID + "=?", new String[] {con_id}, null);

                    if(phoneCursor.moveToFirst()){
                        String phone_number=phoneCursor.getString(phoneCursor.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER));
                        number.setText(phone_number);
                    }
                    phoneCursor.close();
                }
            }


        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can save data of contact or whole phonebook into SQLite or Shared preferences. You can find more here: https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage

Also btw Shared Preferences is easier for use, its a key/value store where you can save a data under certain key. So for smaller amount of data is probably better option

Answer (score 0):

If the data type you need to store is not complicate, you can use SharedPreferences.

```
public void SaveData(){
    SharedPreferences preferences = getSharedPreferences("phone_data", MODE_PRIVATE);
    // get the editor
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = preferences.edit();
    // store the data in different type
    editor.putString("name", userName);
    editor.putString("phone", phoneNumber);
    // save the data
    editor.apply();
}

public void LoadData(){
    SharedPreferences preferences = getSharedPreferences("phone_data", MODE_PRIVATE);
    userName = preferences.getString("name", "");
    userPhone = preferences.getString("phoneNumber", "");
    // do whatever you want with your data now!
}
```